# Why I do not get 'overflow error'?

Tags: c++, c

I wrote this small piece of code based on 'memcpy' man page. I executed it but I did not get any error. Normally, I should get 'seg fault' because I tried to copy a message to small size destination.

```
char str1[1];
char str2[] = "Big Message";

memcpy(&str1, &str2, strlen(str2));
```

Comment: See [Is accessing a global array outside its bound undefined behavior?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26426910/1708801)

Comment: MULTI DUP............

Comment: 'Normally, I should get 'seg fault'  - who told you that?

Comment: I know it's UB too, shouldn't be `memcpy(str1, str2, strlen(str2));`?

Answer (score 8):

**[Undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior)** is undefined.  Anything could happen.  It could run, crash and burn, take out the internet, crash a car through your wall.

Comment: [another interesting link](http://blog.regehr.org/archives/213) to understand what undefined behaviour implies

Comment: If compiler detect undefined behavior. Why It generate executable and not generate a compilation error?

Comment: A compiler is not required to throw an error on using undefined behavior.  see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417883/why-doesnt-compile-issue-an-error-for-code-that-results-in-undefined-behavior

Comment: Because that's what UB means. Compilable code with valid syntax, that will burn everything around you.

Answer (score 4):

Why did you expect to get a "seg fault"?

"Seg fault" is something that happens on some platforms when you attempt to access an address region that's protected by the OS and/or hardware. In your case you `memcpy` did not run into any such regions.

In fact, getting a "seg fault" in response to such error is a rare and lucky occurrence. Most of the time you will simply quietly destroy your own data located in the adjacent memory region.

Answer (score 2):

Segfault (thanks to @zneak) means accessing memory in a way that virtual memory won't let you. In most cases, this is due to trying to dereference a NULL pointer.

In this case, you instead have a buffer overrun (which means undefined behavior, which means that it could very well work on your computer and crash and burn on another).

Comment: Segfault means accessing memory in a way virtual memory will not let you. It isn't necessarily dereferencing the NULL pointer. It could be dereferencing an unmapped address, writing to a read-only location, or executing an unexecutable location.

Answer (score 2):

Stepping past the bounds of an array is undefined behavior in C. This means that it is illegal, but the language is not required to do anything specifically if/when it happens.

In other words, if you get a segfault, that's awesome! It'll be easier to debug. But unfortunately, you won't necessarily get one. In your case, you're merely overwriting adjacent memory. C has no runtime information about array bounds, and as such cannot enforce them.

On the Linux system, the stack is allocated as a large, contiguous block of read-write (and sometimes executable) memory. You won't get a segmentation fault unless you write so much data that you pass the bounds of the stack itself.

Comment: "C has no runtime information about array bounds, and as such cannot enforce them." is more like "C does not specify runtime array bounds,",  A given implementation _could_ enforce them.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to check for some illegal memory accesses compile it with `-fsanitize=address` (at least gcc 4.8 required and libasan must be installed) and you'll get an error report:

```
==4926==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow on address 0x7ffd1f1a4bf1 at pc 0x7f259efeadc4 bp 0x7ffd1f1a4bc0 sp 0x7ffd1f1a4368
WRITE of size 11 at 0x7ffd1f1a4bf1 thread T0
    #0 0x7f259efeadc3 in __asan_memcpy (/lib64/libasan.so.2+0x8cdc3)
    #1 0x4008c0 in main (/home/m/a.out+0x4008c0)
    #2 0x7f259ebbe78f in __libc_start_main (/lib64/libc.so.6+0x2078f)
    #3 0x400728 in _start (/home/m/a.out+0x400728)

Address 0x7ffd1f1a4bf1 is located in stack of thread T0 at offset 33 in frame
    #0 0x400805 in main (/home/m/a.out+0x400805)

  This frame has 2 object(s):
    [32, 33) 'str1' <== Memory access at offset 33 overflows this variable
    [96, 108) 'str2'
HINT: this may be a false positive if your program uses some custom stack unwind mechanism or swapcontext
      (longjmp and C++ exceptions *are* supported)
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: stack-buffer-overflow ??:0 __asan_memcpy
```